# Error in load_private_package("glue") : Cannot load glue from the private library

Tags: r, installation, package, pak

I'm trying to install `R` packages using `pak` `R` package as follows:

```
library(pak)
pkg_install("usethis")
```

However, I'm getting the following error message with all packages:

```
Error in load_private_package("glue") : 
  Cannot load glue from the private library
```

**Session Info**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pak_0.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13   knitr_1.37.4      xml2_1.3.3       
 [4] magrittr_2.0.2    rvest_1.0.2       munsell_0.5.0    
 [7] colorspace_2.0-3  viridisLite_0.4.0 R6_2.5.1         
[10] rlang_1.0.1.9000  fastmap_1.1.0     stringr_1.4.0    
[13] httr_1.4.2        tools_4.1.2       webshot_0.5.2    
[16] pacman_0.5.1      xfun_0.29.3       cli_3.2.0        
[19] htmltools_0.5.2   systemfonts_1.0.4 digest_0.6.29    
[22] lifecycle_1.0.1   kableExtra_1.3.4  purrr_0.3.4      
[25] glue_1.6.1        evaluate_0.15     rmarkdown_2.11.22
[28] stringi_1.7.6     compiler_4.1.2    scales_1.1.1     
[31] svglite_2.1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it removing pak and reinstalling it with
`install.packages("pak", type = "source")`

Comment: (I took the idea from https://github.com/r-lib/pak/issues/339)